# Is there any documentation describing the Azure Portal user interface?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I'm looking for any documentation that explains the various components (blades, tiles, parts, etc.) comprising the Azure Portal. My team is creating technical documents and having a resource with official component names, definitions, and explanations would be a useful resource for writing our materials.

Comment: You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-portal-experience/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-portal